# Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property setNumberFormats on object SpreadsheetApp.Range

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script I've been running successfully for a couple weeks now but this week it has started failing with the error shown above. I have not changed anything in the script, so I don't know why this is suddenly happening every time I run it.

Was there a release or server side issue that could have caused this fallout? Like I said this code and any code that fed into it have not been changed since it was working fine and the error is providing me with no other information. This is also not the only function experiencing the problem, every time I try to use setNumberFormats it is failing.

Sorry that this is broad, but the issue I'm experiencing **is** broad.

```
function pasteObjectsToSheet(objects, range, locations) {
  const values = []
  const formats = []
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    var object = objects[i]
    var value = new Array(locations.length)
    var format = new Array(locations.length)
    for (var key in object) {
      var index = locations.indexOf(key)
      if (index > -1) {
        value[index] = object[key].value
        format[index] = object[key].format
      }
    }
    values.push(value)
    formats.push(format)
  }
  range.setValues(values)
  range.setNumberFormats(formats)
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a sample spreadhseet or script so that the rest of the users can figure out where the issue might be located. Thanks ! :D

Comment: I've added one of the functions experiencing the problem, but it is happening every time I try to use setNumberFormats across multiple sheets

Comment: Turns out it was a pretty simple explanation, I guess a stray click or keyboard press caused me to change one variable assignment from "format" to "formt" so it was trying to set the number format to undefined!

Comment: Hi ! Could you leave that explanation as an answer to your question so that everyone encountering the same issue can easily find the solution and make sure they did not misswrote something? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue of the original poster in this question was a typo. Instead of writing `format` in `format[index] = object[key].format` he wrote `formt`.